# Convolution with Gaussian White Noise?

Tags: convolution

I am just curious about what would happen if a signal is convoluted with a Gaussian white noise with zero mean? Can anyone provide a quick explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Rough explanation would be the signal will become more smooth, fluctuations will be averaged out.